# AngularJS send message to iOS WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, wkwebview

I'm running a local webserver in my iOS App that serves an AngularJS app but I don't know how to communicate between the WKWebView and my controller.

In iOS, `viewDidLoad`

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[wkWebConfig.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];


self.webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame ];
[self.webview setBackgroundColor:self.view.backgroundColor];

[self.webview loadRequest:request];
```

And from angularJS controller, I need to get the `wkwebview` object but is undefined:

```
$scope.showSettings = function(){
     //this is undefined
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage(message)
}
```

If I try it within the `head` tag of my web page, it works perfectly fine.

```
<script>
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage(message)
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this link (http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) , It may help you.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. Did you happen to find a fix?

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine if I use `<script>window.webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage(message)</script>` within my `head` tag. Although if used anywhere within Angular, it does not work at all.

Comment: What specifically is undefined? `webkit`, `messageHandlers`, or `interOp`?

Answer (score 6):

You're not doing anything wrong, Some *evil* frameworks and libraries override the `window.webkit` global, I'm not sure which one, but with some testing I'm sure you can find out.

To overcome this you need to cache the global before any interfering script overrides it.

This can be done either in JavaScript located at the head of the document or in Objective-C via injection.

**Javascript**

```
...<head>
<script>
(function () {
    window.myUniqueNamespace.messageHandlers = window.webkit.messageHandlers;
}());
</script>
```

And boom, your variable is safe and sound at `window.myUniqueNamespace.messageHandlers`

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *myScriptSource = @"(function() {window.myUniqueNamespace.messageHandlers=window.webkit.messageHandlers;}());";
WKUserScript *myUserScript = [[WKUserScript alloc]
 initWithSource:myScriptSource
 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
 forMainFrameOnly:YES];
```

*Note: I have no way to test this or have experience in Objective-C, but I had a similar issue with JavaFX's webkit webview.

Here's a useful presentation about the [WebKit API](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/206xxdiurnffagr/206/206_introducing_the_modern_webkit_api.pdf)

Comment: Very nice solution actually. Storing it as it's own namespace to stop it from being over written. I ended up just going down the path of creating a global function - yet we all know that's never a good idea! Thanks.